# One-to-many using EF5 fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, poco

Using EF5, I want a one-to-many mapping for `Car:Wheel == 1:0..n`

```
public class Car {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

public class Wheel {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  // I don't want to define a reverse relationship here
}
```

So for `Car` I did:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
  .HasMany(x => x.Wheels)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(x => x
    .MapLeftKey("CarID")
    .MapRightKey("WheelID")
    .ToTable("Car_Wheel"));
```

Which gives me an `n:n` join table. But I want `1:n`.

Do I need to define a unique constraint on `Car_Wheel.CarID` (if so, how?), or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want 1:n

Use `WithRequired` or `WithOptional`:

```
modelBuilder
            .Entity<MyParentEntity>()
            .HasMany(_ => _.Children)
            .WithRequired() //.WithOptional()
            .Map(/* map association here */);
```

But it will be better, if you will use foreign key associations:

```
public class Wheel 
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int CarID { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyParentEntity>()
    .HasMany(_ => _.Children)
    .WithRequired() //.WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(_ => _.ParentId);
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately this creates an FK in the Children table. I don't want such a key for design reasons. This would be the correct approach however.

Comment: The first case (with `Map`) uses independent associations (thus, it doesn't use any foreign key).

Comment: Just tried it to be sure, it creates an FK in the Children table. If you omit `.Map()` then it just names that key according to conventions, but it is in there. I can't have that key. I think the join table is unavoidable, but I'm not sure how to fool it into behaving as 1:1.